# Can't access property from parent class

Tags: php, oop, properties, constructor, parent

The only thing I'm trying to achieve is to be able to access the `Sql` property in class **A** from class **B**, but my understanding must be completely off the grid.

I tried:

```
class A {
    public $Sql; /*object*/

    public function __construct() {
        $this->Sql = new MySQLi("localhost", "user", "password", "database");
    }
}

class B extends A {

    public function __construct() {
        $this->foo();
    }

    public function foo() {
        var_dump($this->Sql); // NULL
        var_dump(parent::Sql); // Error due to Sql not being a constant, can't set an object as a constant.
    }

}

$A = new A();
$B = new B();
```

But the code is not behaving as I would hope it does.

Hoping someone can point me in the right direction on where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$A = new A();
$B = new B();
```

These two lines above create 2 different object, which don't have anything to do with each other.

So since you also have a constructor in class B the parent [constructor doesn't get called implicit](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php), means you have to change your code and call the constructor from class A in class B, e.g.

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->foo();
}
```

Comment: That feeling of clarity just brushed over me, thank you - will accept this answer in 7 minutes when it allows me to.

Comment: @Zanderwar You're welcome. Enjoy your day :) (BTW: I can only highly recommend you to take a look into the linked manual page.)